# How can I use relative paths with AutoHotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use relative path in AutoHotKeys so the source control can be checked out and the hotkeys will still work.

Using `%A_WorkingDir%` gives me the location of the script. From there I need to move up one directory and nagivate down to the script I need to run.

I have tried:

```
^!a::
    Path = %A_WorkingDir%
    Run %Path%\..\locationOf\script.cmd
```

---

```
^!a::
    Path = %A_WorkingDir%\..
    Run %Path%\locationOf\script.cmd
```

---

```
^!a::
    Path = %A_WorkingDir% \..
    Run %Path%\locationOf\script.cmd
```

---

```
^!a::
    Path = %A_WorkingDir% "\.." ; Also removed the space between % and " -> %A_WorkingDir%"\.." but didn't work
    Run %Path%\locationOf\script.cmd
```

I don't really want to do any string manipulation on the working dir to force it unless there is no other way?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Run "%A_WorkingDir%\..\locationOf\script.cmd"` ? I think you forgot the quotes... if that doesnt work... try this : `Run %comspec% /k "%A_WorkingDir%\..\locationOf\script.cmd"` notice, i specified `%comspec%`

Comment: This works. `Run %A_ScriptDir%\..\scripts\build.cmd`. There must be some problem with creating a variable to hold the location. Thanks. Post as an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try**
`Run %A_WorkingDir%\..\locationOf\script.cmd`
**Or**
`Run "%A_WorkingDir%\..\locationOf\script.cmd"`
**Or**
`Run %comspec% /k "%A_WorkingDir%\..\locationOf\script.cmd"`

---

**As BGM has said :**

> Keep in mind that the workingdir can also be changed via a windows launcher or shortcut. If you use a launcher like JetToolbar (my favourite) it sets the workingdir to its own application directory by default. It might be a good idea for the script to set the workingdir to the scriptdir or just use scriptdir instead.

**Solution :**
`SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%`

Comment: Joe DF to the rescue!  It might be well to keep in mind that the `workingdir` can also be changed via a windows launcher or shortcut.  If you use a launcher like JetToolbar (my favourite) it sets the workingdir to its own application directory by default.  It might be a good idea for the script to set the `workingdir` to the `scriptdir` or just use `scriptdir` instead.

Comment: Sure - it will make the answer more complete and folks won't have to read the comments.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: `SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%` (which is set in the default template for new ahk scripts) will generally eliminate the workingdir vs scriptdir problem.

Comment: @MCL yes, true. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Just adding my comment here, it seems like variables can be used in the Run, it is just that the ".." has to be within the Run command as text as follows: `Run, % A_ScriptDir "\..\" FileName, % A_ScriptDir "\..\"`

Comment: that's specifying it as an expression. Works as well, but mainly just a different coding style.